# Is there any way to get the number of records visited for a specific MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb

When doing a specific query, I am curious if there is any way to retrieve the exact number of records MongoDB had to visit before finding the results. Is there any way to get this stat?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the [db.collection.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) to generate a query plan. Explain with "executionStats" mode generates query execution  statistics. I think you will find the relevant info in the output document.

Comment: The [Database Profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/index.html) will collect that info from each query.  serverStatus contains an overall count of documents examined for the entire instance.